# SVG map not rendering in communities?

Tags: community

I have developed a lightning application and it works properly, i want to use it in **communities** every thing works except the **svg** map that is invisible to the users.

i checked the debugger and i noticed that:

[image]

I do not know how to make work it knowing that the **svg** file with other JavaScript files are loaded as static resources.

Edit: here the code of my component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="realEstateController" access="global">

    <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
                           '/resource/jQuery',
                           '/resource/departmentMap/jquery.vmap.js',
                           '/resource/departmentMap/jquery.vmap.france.js',
                           '/resource/departmentMap/jquery.vmap.colorsFrance.js')}"
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />

    <aura:attribute name="departmentName" type="String" access="global"/>
    <aura:attribute name="propertiesCount" type="Map" access="global"/>    
    <aura:attribute name="programsCount" type="Map" access="global"/>    
    <aura:attribute name="propertyCount" type="Integer" access="global"/>
    <aura:attribute name="programCount" type="Integer" access="global"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedDeparment" type="Integer" access="global"/>

    <aura:registerEvent name="sendDepartment" type="c:realEstateSendFiltersEvent"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}"/>


    <!--<div style="background:rgb(255,255,255)">-->

            <div>
                Département : {!v.departmentName}
            </div>
            <div>
                Nombre de programmes : {!v.programCount}
            </div>
            <div>
                Nombre de lots : {!v.propertyCount}
            </div>


        <div class="francemap" style="background-color: transparent;">

        </div>    
   <!-- </div>-->
        <!--</div>
    </div>-->

</aura:component>
```

Comment: Please post the code for your component.

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: While I don't see where you're specifically calling the svg icon, your code may be calling it and you've not declared those two aura attributes if the svg file is actually used in your component. What version of jQuery are you using? Only 2.2.2 and 2.2.4 are supported by the locker service.

Comment: actually, the svg is created dynamically inside one of the script files, regarding jQuery, i do not think it's the cause of the error as it works perfectly in lightning experience

Comment: The only question left other than version would seem to be whether your resource is available to community users?

Comment: how can i check that ?

Comment: Look at the resource file in Setup under Static Resouces (use Search to find). Use Edit and make certain "Cache Control" is set to public. If your component is namespaced, you may need to add the namespace to the path used in the component.